# How to copy queries by folder in Team Explorer's Work Items pan

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem

In Visual Studio(2015 Update 3) I want to copy all my TFS work item queries.
The queries are placed in multiple nested folders hierarchically.
As I remember, I used to do this task simply by copying the top level folder.
However,recently I noticed that the Copy functionality is not available for folders as it is grayed out in their context menu.

Whats the workaround?

By the way any solution using TFS Sdk is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017, the Copy option for query folder is grayed out, and it only supports to copy a specific query not a query folder. You could use Visual Studio 2013 to copy a query folder. This is supports in VS2013.

As another workaround, you could select all queries your want to copy and right-click, choose **Copy**.

[image]

Here is an feedback that someone has reported about this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41216/able-to-copy-shared-query-folder-with-vs2013-ide-b.html

Comment: The trouble with this is it doesn't copy the CHARTS attached to queries as well